# How to Reference the page (view) the viewmodel is for?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I already had someone help with this before, but now that I am rewriting everything into MVVM, I have lost the ability to do this... Again!

Pre-MVVM rewrite, I had this line of code in the code behind my page:

```
var window = MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>(this);
```

right at the end, the "this" meant the page. Now, this code is sitting in my viewmodel with a squiggly red line, and I don't know what to replace it with. I don't think I can put:

```
SideBar sb = new SideBar();
var window = MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>(sb);
```

because this would create a new instance of sidebar... wouldn't it? This page is loaded as the default source of a frame within the mainpage btw, not initiated via code.

Comment: Never try to rewrite code like this 1:1... Your viewmodel shouldn't call any method like this at all! Rethink your approach, because MVVM isn't `take my code from codebehind and put it into a separate class`.

Comment: For a lot of it I haven't been doing that... But I am completely unfamiliar with what's going on in this line really... and I want to achieve the same effect. Do you know what I might be able to do instead?

Comment: Well it obviously tries to find the parent of the object, in this case the parent of a Page, which would be the Window... Not sure how do you use it in the code later on, but your ViewModel shouldn't know anything about the Window, nor the Page. You need to put that logic elsewhere, IF you even need it...

Comment: The very next line of code is:

    await DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync(window, "MESSAGE HERE");

as far as I am aware, there is no way yo call this without knowing about the window.... and I don't know where else this code could go?

Comment: Well it should notify some other class to show the message, but it should never be directly responsible for dealing with stuff like this. As far as it knows, it only triggers showing a message, but it's up to someone else to do it. ViewModel shouldn't care if it's a WPF messagebox, or a website javascript popup or even some console output.. That's what is MVVM about - separation of layers and concerns to make the code testable, manageable and reusable. Avoid as much tight coupling as possible. HOW exactly achieve that is a matter of a long discussion and there's no definitive answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the window as a parameter of some action to your view model.

```
<Button Content="Test"
    Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

And on your view model command grab the parameter

```
ShowPopupCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    var wnd = o as Window;
});
```

Code for `RelayCommand`

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    where T : class
{
    private Action<T> execute;
    private Func<T, bool> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter as T);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter as T);
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : RelayCommand<object>
{
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        : base(execute, canExecute)
    {
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ShowPopupCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            var wnd = o as Window;
            var putBreakPointhere = 1;
        });
    }

    public ICommand ShowPopupCommand { get; set; }
}
```

[image: wnd]

Comment: How would you test VM like this?

Comment: I can't get the param to pass... This is what I have ATM, where should I put the param?

    statsRefresh = new RelayCommand(param => this.StatsRefresh_Click(), null);

Then, my method:

    public void StatsRefresh_Click(MetroWindow window)

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I am still confused though, sorry! I already have a relay command, but it is a bit different - Can I paste that relay command in also and overload it? Then... by running the ShowPopupCommand = new RelayCommand(... Would that run a seperate method? My current command passes the relay command the method I want to run... but I don't see that in yours? Sorry! :(

Comment: @BrunoLM: In which world is this valid MVVM pattern?

Comment: @Tseng say you want to reference the window to close it, how else would you achieve it without referencing the window?

Comment: Event Aggregator, Navigation Service or Windows Service. All of them only get passed as interfaces. Or make an `IWindow` or `IClosable` interface with a single `void Close()` method and have your window implement it (since. Using `Window` type requires a reference to `System.Window` class. This is already tight coupling. Same as referencing your View assembly from your ViewModel assembly. Since `Window`already implement it, all you got to do is add it to the class declaration: `public partial class MyWindow : Window, IWindow`

Comment: The `IWindow`/`IClosable` method still won't allow you to close it from ViewModel btw. That's where are more complex Navigation Service or Windows Service comes into play which manages all ViewModel <-> View/Windows relations. The `INavigationService` or `IWindowService` is declared in your ViewModel assembly, but is impemented int the `View` assembly. So you can use Window and View related references within the concrete implementation, but not within the interface declaration. `windowsService.Close<PersonViewModel>()` is okay, `windowsService.Close<PersonWindow>()` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the new `Sidebar` instance to the visual tree, so of course there's no `MetroWindow` parent, since it has no parent at all.

I suggest to make yourself more familiar with the MVVM pattern. The view model should have no notion of the actual UI. I've written a [small MVVM library](https://github.com/thoemmi/TinyLittleMvvm) based on MahApps.Metro and Autofac, maybe it could be a starting point for you.